# Recurrence event with RRULE plugin Timezone issue daylight saving time

Tags: fullcalendar, dst, recurrence, rrule

The problem occurs when you have an event, which starts for example on October 23 11:45, repeats every day, with no end date

Once October 30 reaches, this event starts to be shown from 10:45 (Because in my country daylight saving time happens on a night from 29 to 30 October)

Is there are any way to prevent this behaviour ?

What I tried already: use tzid on RRULE plugin which I'm using for recurrence
Changing timezone of fullcalendar itself (per parameter) is not an option for me

I'll attach fullcalendar representation of this problem

I'm expecting to see that event starting at 11:45 and not 10:45

[Event series before savings day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHkFe.png)
[Event series after savings day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Rwk.png)

You can notice how hour chagned

Comment: Did you get a working solution to this problem? I'm running into the exact issue and have been searching high and low for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem. There seems to be an [open issue on the GitHub repo that has a monkeypatch workaround](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5273#issuecomment-1360459342):

```js
rrulePlugin.recurringTypes[0].expand = function (errd, fr, de) {
  const hours = errd.rruleSet._dtstart.getHours();
  return errd.rruleSet.between(de.toDate(fr.start), de.toDate(fr.end), true).map((d) => {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hours, d.getMinutes()));
  });
};
```